# Run a set of linux commands using Jenkinsfile in Jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I had to create a jenkins job to automate certain tasks that will perform certain operations like Updating the public site, Changing public version to latest public release, Updating Software on public site and Restarting Server these include certain operations such as copy files to a tmp folder, log in to a an on-prem server, go to the folder and unzip the file etc.
I have created the jenkinsfile as follows:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
        string(name: 'filename', defaultValue: 'abc', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        string(database: 'database', defaultValue: 'abc', description: 'Enter the database that needs to be created')
        choice(name: 'Run', choices: '', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    agent {
        node { label 'aws && build && linux && ubuntu' }
    }
    triggers {
        pollSCM('H/5 * * * *')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Clean & Clone') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Updating the public site'){
            steps{
                sh "scp ./${filename}.zip <user>@<server name>:/tmp"
                sh "ssh <user>@<server name>"
                sh "cp ./tmp/${filename}.zip ./projects/xyz/xyz-site/"
                sh "cd ./projects/xyz/xyz-site/ "
                sh "unzip ./${filename}.zip"
                sh "cp -R ./${filename}/* ./"
        }
        stage('Changing public version to latest public release') {
            steps {
                sh "scp ./${filename}.sql.gz <user>@<server name>:/tmp"
                sh "ssh <user>@<server name>"
                sh "mysql -u root -p<PASSWORD>"
                sh "show databases;"
                sh "create database ${params.database};"
                sh "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <newdb>.* TO 'ixxyz'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;"
                sh "exit;"
                sh "zcat tmp/${filename}.sql.gz | mysql -u root -p<PASSWORD> <newdb>"
                sh "db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<newdb>""    
                sh "ps aux|grep monitor.sh|awk '{print "kill "$2}' |bash"             
            }
        }
        stage('Updating Software on public site') {
            steps {
                sh "scp <user>@<server>:/tmp/abc<version>_empty_h2.zip"
                sh "ssh <user>@<server name>"
                sh "su <user>"
                sh "mv tmp/<version>_empty_h2.zip ./xyz/projects/xyz"
                sh "cd xyz/projects/xyz"
                sh "cp latest/conf/local.conf <version>_empty_h2/conf/"         
            }    
        }
        stage('Restarting Server') {
            steps {
                sh "rm latest/RUNNING_PID"
                sh "bash reload.sh"
                sh "nohup bash monitor.sh &"       
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can dynamically obtain the zip filename in the root folder? I used `${filename}.zip` , but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, is there a better way to perform these operations using jenkins? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try  using the absolute path to ${filename}.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write all your steps in one shell script for each stage and execute under one stage.
Regarding `filename.zip`either you can take this as a `parameter` and pass this value to your stages. OR You can also use `find` command as a shell command or shell script to find .zip files in a current directory.
 `find <dir> -iname \*.zip` 
`find . -iname \*.zip` .

Example:

```
pipeline {
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        timestamps()
    }
    parameters {
         
         string(name: 'filename', defaultValue: 'abc', description: 'Enter the file name that needs to be copied')
        choice(name: 'Run', choices: '', description: 'Data migration')
    }
    stage('Updating the public site'){
            steps{
                sh "scp ./${params.filename}.zip <user>@<server name>:/tmp"
                ...
            }
        }
}
```

For executing script at a certain location based on your question , you could use `dir` with path  where your scripts are placed.
OR you can also give the path directly `sh label: 'execute script', script:"C:\\Data\\build.sh"`

```
stage('Your stage name'){
            steps{
                   script {
                           // Give path where your scripts are placed
                           dir ("C:\\Data") {
                             sh label: 'execute script', script:"build.sh <Your Arguments> "
                ...
                            }
                   }
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is a better way so that the user can enter the file name in jenkins and the name of the file is passed on to the script. Does executing all the commands in one stage will provide any benefit? Isn't it easy to distinguish each stage so that it's easy to track? Also, is there a way I can pass the password to the script? One way, I am thinking of is by storing it in the config files in Jenkins and pass it as an ARG. Any other better way?

Comment: @merilstack : You can keep all stages and have a shell script for each stage.I just gave an example for one stage.Yes you can pass the password by argument to this script . Eg: ``` sh(script "script1 --password ="<your password>" ")``` or you can also use credentails of jenkins and pass that variable as an input to your script

Comment: @merilstack do you need any other information

Comment: so if I pass a shell script for each stages, then they should be placed in the same folder as the Jenkinsfile in the source code right?

Comment: @merilstack yes or you also give the path wherever your script is residing.Eg : ``dir("C:\\Data")`` { <your script execution> }`` I have added this in the answer

Comment: what I meant was the script will be placed in a source code like github, so the shell script must be placed in the same folder as where the script is present?

Comment: @merilstack yes thats right if you want it version controlled  or you can also place in workspace or slave machine

Comment: once logged into the server can I run mysql commands using this Jenkinsfile as well? For eg: ```sh "create database <newdb>;"```, ```sh "db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<newdb>""``` and ```sh "ps aux|grep monitor.sh|awk '{print "kill "$2}' |bash" ```

Comment: @merilstack you can create a shell script and execute all sql commands inside it with your sql username and password.

Comment: @merilstack Request you to accept the answer if it solves your question

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Can you please share me an example on how to do this ie running the sql commands in the shell script? That will be really helpful, thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233479/discussion-between-altaf-and-merilstack).